# Tengo problemas en mi proyecto laravel 5.5

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel-5

Me aparece este error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clientes.deleted_at' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `clientes` where `clientes`.`deleted_at` is null)

Genere mis `controllers` y mis vistas con el generador `infyom` y cuando quiero acceder a la ruta de crear un cliente me sucede esto.

Answer (score 1):

El error es porque el gestor de base de datos de Laravel busca la columna `deleted_at` en tu tabla `clientes`, y esa columna no existe. Laravel usa esa columna para habilitar la característica de "soft deleting" (Ver [Documentación de Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting)).

Tienes dos opciones:

1. Crear la columna `deleted_at` en la tabla `clientes`. Debe ser de tipo `DATETIME` o similar.
2. Deshabilitar el "soft deleting" eliminando (o comentando) en tu modelo `Clientes` la línea que dice `protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];`.